# how to use setParameter for date field in where condition in sql query " date like :today " using hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am having trouble while trying to implement where condition with **" punchDate like :date1 "** in sql query using hibernate. Can any one please tell me what is the correct syntax to implement it.

```
String sql=select * from PunchHistory whered punchDate like :date1;
String date="2017-10-23";
List<PunchHistory> results =session.createQuery(StackperksConstants.sql)
                    .setDate("date1", java.sql.Date.valueOf(date))
                    .list();
```

Could anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have "whered" did you realise?

Answer (score 1):

`Like` is used with Strings, instead you have to use `=` with dates :

```
String sql="select * from PunchHistory where punchDate = :date1"
//-----------------------------------------------------^
List<PunchHistory> results = 
                 session.createQuery(StackperksConstants.sql)
                 .setParameter("date1", java.sql.Date.valueOf(date), TemporalType.TIMESTAM)
//Instead you can use -----^
                 .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is using the `setParameter()` method, for example:

```
session.createQuery(sql,Class.class).setPrameter(0,date,TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).list();
```